# select option no bindea mis datos Angular6

Tags: angular, angular6

tengo un formulario reactivo que utiliza el FormBuilder para manejar los campos pero cuando quiero cargar por defecto un array simple de string en un select option no se muestra en el html.
Así declaro en Typescript

```
 constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  }
 forma: FormGroup;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.forma = this.fb.group({
fecha: ['', Validators.required],
      lstFormaPago: [['Efectivo', 'Cheque', 'Tarjeta'], Validators.required]
 });
  }
```

Esta es mi pagina de formulario

```
    <form autocomplete="off" [formGroup]="forma" (ngSubmit)="guardar()" >
 <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Fecha</label>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <input class="form-control"
                     type="date"
                     placeholder="01/01/2020"
                     formControlName="fecha" >
            </div>
          </div>
 <div class="form-group row">
<label class="col-md-2 col-form-label">FormaPago</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
<select formControlName="lstFormaPago" class="form-control">
                <option *ngFor="let form of lstFormaPago">{{form}}</option>// <- No muestra valores
              </select>
</div>
</div> 
</div>
</form>
```

He intentado pasar en una variable el array desde typescript, quintando validators, reemplzando formControlName por ng-model="lstFormaPago" y  nada

Answer (score 1):

Estás haciendo mal las cosas, en primera estás inicializando `lstFormaPago` como un arreglo, esto es el valor que va a tener tu select mas no las opciones del select, en segunda el `lstFormaPago`que usas en el `*ngFor`no existe a menos que no hayas mostrado tu parte del código. La solucion es declarar una variable que contenga tu arreglo de valores para el select y una vez que se seleccione algo, se hará la interpolacion en automatico al form control  `lstFormaPago`.

```
        constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}
        forma: FormGroup;
        listaFormaPago = ['Efectivo', 'Cheque', 'Tarjeta'];

        ngOnInit() {
            this.forma = this.fb.group({
                  fecha: ['', Validators.required],
                  formaPago: ['', Validators.required]
            });
        }
```

Para este caso el form control lo inicializo con un valor vacio, por lo que si no se selecciona algo se dispara el validador de required. Está en tu decición poner un option vació al select para este caso.

```
       <form autocomplete="off" [formGroup]="forma" (ngSubmit)="guardar()" >
           <div class="form-group row">
               <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Fecha</label>
               <div class="col-md-3">
                   <input class="form-control" type="date"
                          placeholder="01/01/2020"
                          formControlName="fecha" >
               </div>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group row">
               <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label">FormaPago</label>
               <div class="col-md-4">
                   <select formControlName="formaPago" class="form-control">
                       <option value="">- Seleccione -</option>
                       <option *ngFor="let form of listaFormaPago" [value]="form">{{form}}</option>// <- No muestra valores
                   </select>
               </div>
           </div> 
         </div>
     </form>
```

Comment: te agradezco @Alberto Rojas, me estaba confundiendo por las diferentes formas de cargar las <options>  ,dado que para campos tipo text si funciona poner directo el valor en la construción del fb.group()